# Inequality with binomial coefficients, prove ${2n-l\choose n-k}\leq {2n-l \choose \frac{2n-l}{2}}$.

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $n, l \in \mathbb{N}, l\leq n$ be fixed. Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 \leq k \leq l$.
How to show the following?

> $${2n-l\choose n-k}\leq {2n-l \choose \frac{2n-l}{2}}$$

Comment: Is $l$ even?${}$

Comment: No, $l$ is any.

Comment: So you're using the Gamma function definition of $\binom{7}{7/2}$?

Comment: Yes, or just a Stirling formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Prove that $$\displaystyle \begin{cases} \binom{2N}{r} < \binom{2N}{r+1} & \text{when } r \leq N-1\\ \binom{2N}{r+1} < \binom{2N}{r} & \text{when } r \geq N \end{cases}$$

> We have that $$\binom{2N}{r+1} = \binom{2N}{r} \times \left( \frac{2N-r}{r+1} \right).$$ Note that $$ \begin{cases} \left( \frac{2N -r}{r+1} \right) > 1 & r \leq N - 1\\ \left( \frac{2N -r}{r+1} \right) < 1 & r \geq N \end{cases}$$ Hence, we have that $$\begin{cases} \binom{2N}{r} < \binom{2N}{r+1} & \text{when } r \leq N-1\\ \binom{2N}{r+1} < \binom{2N}{r} & \text{when } r \geq N \end{cases}$$

Comment: Tank you, but I stil don't see how to use it for my inequality. Could you elaborate, please. Thank you.

Comment: @user202312 In your case, choose $N = 2n-l$. Essentially, you want to prove that the middle binomial coefficient is the largest.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Calculate

$$\frac{{2n-l\choose m+1}}{{2n-l\choose m}}$$

Can you find out when the fraction is more/less than 1?